# Backup of AWS ec2 root drive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, backup, aws-backup

I have an ec2 instance with one volume as root drive.

I've set a AWS backup of the volume, is this the best procedure or should I ec2 backup not the volume.

I can't work out if restoring the volume and attaching it to an instance will bring it back, or if using ec2 backup and restoring will also bring back the information on the volume.

Any info would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't work out if restoring the volume and attaching it to an
>   instance will bring it back, or if using ec2 backup and restoring will
>   also bring back the information on the volume.

Both will work. The EC2 backup will be a little easier to recover because you won't have to manually connect the restored volume to an instance. The EC2 backup includes an EBS snapshot of any volumes attached to the instance.